# ¿Cómo comparo dos cadenas en crystal?

Tags: string, crystal-lang

estoy tratando de comparar dos cadenas para un ejercicio pero el uso de `==` no me ha servido, ya que nunca entra al segundo `if`.

Este es mi código:

```
def name_in_str(str, name)
  current_letter = 0
  name_letters = name.upcase.split("")
  0.upto(str.size-1) do |i|
    if current_letter == name.size
      return true
    end
    puts "-#{str[i].upcase}- == #{name_letters[current_letter]} -> #{current_letter}"
    if str[i].upcase == name_letters[current_letter]
      current_letter = current_letter + 1
    end
  end
  return current_letter == name.size
end
```

Mi traza produce el siguiente log:

> Testing for "Across the rivers" and "chris"  Log
>
> -A- == C -> 0
>
> -C- == C -> 0
>
> -R- == C -> 0
>
> -O- == C -> 0
>
> -S- == C -> 0
>
> -S- == C -> 0
>
> - - == C -> 0
>
> -T- == C -> 0
>
> -H- == C -> 0
>
> -E- == C -> 0
>
> - - == C -> 0
>
> -R- == C -> 0
>
> -I- == C -> 0
>
> -V- == C -> 0
>
> -E- == C -> 0
>
> -R- == C -> 0
>
> -S- == C -> 0 Test Failed Expected: true
>
> ```
>  got: false
> ```

Tengo Crystal en su versión `0.24.2`.
¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lección aprendida, **un índice de una cadena nos da un caracter**, lo cual tiene mucha lógica.

Por esta razón falla al **comparar un caracter con una cadena**.

la solución es simplemente convertirlos a un **mismo tipo**.

```
str[i].upcase.to_s == name_letters[current_letter]
```